# Uploading multiple files at once to Rails app with Carrierwave (HTML5)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, html, file-upload, carrierwave

I'm close...very close...I'm able to upload single files just fine...but when i change the type of my form's `file_field` to `:multiple => true` so I can upload multiple images at once my uploaded files get wrapped in an array...and the 'magic' of 'accepts_nested_attributes_for` is lost.

**Edit:**
After more examination I wonder if I even need to bother with `accepts_nested_attributes_for`? Perhaps I should just have a `file_field, :multiple => true` in my Gallery form (as opposed to a nested form) and then in my create action create the new gallery and then loop through each element in the `params[:gallery][:photos_attributes]["0"][:image]` array by hand, so to speak, calling `@gallery.photos.create` for each element. ?!?  Seems cumbersome...but it's all I can come up with.

Hoping someone with more experience with Rails can chime in...

Params:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", 
"authenticity_token"=>"9jXvIwcllct7UyUfo6cvhEucQf2u3SY50SuaCLtFO4c=", 
"gallery"=>{
  "name"=>"First Gallery", 
  "photos_attributes"=>{"0"=>{
    "image"=>[
      #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000104b78978 
        @original_filename="first_test_image.jpg", 
        @content_type="image/jpeg", 
        @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"gallery[photos_attributes][0][image][]\"; filename=\"first_test_image.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n", 
        @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/bQ/bQYZC2ukFZCvbKzEDGRtJE+++TI/-Tmp-/RackMultipart20110622-4459-vz78ee>>, 
      #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000104b78950 
        @original_filename="second_test_image.jpg", 
        @content_type="image/jpeg", 
        @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"gallery[photos_attributes][0][image][]\"; filename=\"second_test_image.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n", 
        @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/bQ/bQYZC2ukFZCvbKzEDGRtJE+++TI/-Tmp-/RackMultipart20110622-4459-1jzhhyg>>
      ]
    }
  }
}, "commit"=>"Save", "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"galleries"}



#app/models/gallery.rb 
class Gallery < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :photos, :dependent => :destroy 
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos 
end 

#app/models/photo.rb 
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :gallery 
  mount_uploader :photo, PhotoUploader 
end 

#config/routes.rb
resources :galleries do
  resources :photo, :only => [:create, :destroy]
end
```

GalleriesController

```
  def new
    @gallery = Gallery.new
    @gallery.photos.build

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @gallery }
    end
  end

  ...

  def create
    @gallery = Gallery.new(params[:gallery])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @gallery.save
        format.html { redirect_to @gallery, notice: 'Gallery was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @gallery, status: :created, location: @gallery }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @gallery.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what's `"utf8"=>"✓"` for? Why the tickmark?

Comment: @Matti:  That goes into params by default when you do a request to the server to tell it what string encoding it is. Check your rails server output and you'll see it there.

Comment: @iWasRobbed: I don't actually use Rails, it just intrigued me. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: did you ever manage to find a solution to this?

Answer (score 4):

You can do a little hack for the params array, something like:

```
aux = []
params[:gallery][:photos_attributes][:image].each do |f|
  aux << {:image => f}
end
params[:post][:photos_attributes] = aux

@gallery = Gallery.new(params[:gallery])
```

I have a similar problem, I know it's an ugly hack, but it works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Ditch accepts_nested_attributes_for and instead add this to your Gallery model.

```
def photos=(attrs)
  attrs.each { |attr| self.photos.build(:image => attr) }
end
```

Also, make sure that photos is in your gallery's accessible attribs in case you're protecting against mass assignment. Otherwise you won't get the photos array hash assignment from your params. I.e.

```
attr_accessible :field1, field2, :photos
```

Comment: i like this approach. but i need to assign the `user_id` from the `session` to each photo...and not sure how?...can't seem to get at `session` from within the model.