# Rails: Nested form with carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, nested-forms, carrierwave

I'm not sure what should go in the controller of the embedded class. The parameters passed does show all the embedded class attributes including image attributes, but only the non-image parameters get saved in the database. This tells me that the issue is not with the choice of ORM (Mongoid in this case) but related to the way I'm using carrier wave:

```
  Parameters: {"article"=>{"name"=>"New article", "comments_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"remote_image_url"=>"", "name"=>"Comment 1", "content"=>"comment content....", "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x10339d880 @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"article[comments_attributes][0][image]\"; filename=\"dh.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n", @original_filename="dh.png", @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/A1/A1SUPUTUFA8BYB5j+RD2L++++TI/-Tmp-/RackMultipart20120228-21178-1vckii1-0>, @content_type="image/png">}}, "content"=>"article content"}, "commit"=>"Create Article", "authenticity_token"=>"i14YuJs4EVKr5PSEw9IwKXcTbQfOP4mjbR95C75J2mc=", "utf8"=>"\342\234\223"}
MONGODB (89ms) freedb['system.namespaces'].find({})
MONGODB (0ms) freedb['articles'].insert([{"name"=>"New article", "comments"=>[{"name"=>"Comment 1", "_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('4f4daf6a58001652ba000012'), "content"=>"comment content...."}], "_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('4f4daf6958001652ba000011'), "content"=>"article content"}])
```

Parent model:

```
class Article
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, :type => String
  field :content, :type => String

  embeds_many :comments

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments
end
```

Child model:

```
require 'carrierwave/mongoid'

class Comment
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, :type => String
  field :content, :type => String

  field :image, :required => true
  field :remote_image_url

  embedded_in :article, :inverse_of => :comments
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

Parent controller:

```
  def new
    @article = Article.new
    @article.comments.build
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new(params[:article])
  end
```

Parent form:

```
<%= form_for(@article, :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>

    <div class = "field">
        <%= f.label :name %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </div>

    <%= f.fields_for :comments do |c| %>
    <p>
        <%= c.label :name %>
        <%= c.text_field :name %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <%= c.label :image, "Select Screenshot from your Computer"%><br />
        <%= c.file_field :image %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <%= c.label :remote_image_url, "or URL from the interweb"%><br />
        <%= c.text_field :remote_image_url %>
    </p>

    <% end %>


    <div class = "actions">
        <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue before. Dave ans work for me.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447278/uploading-multiple-files-at-once-to-rails-app-with-carrierwave-html5

Answer (score 9):

Carrierwave use some callback to save image and data in your model. By default embedded model have no callback execute. You need say explicitly that your embed need execute his callback.

To do that use the `cascade_callbacks: true` option.

```
embeds_many :comments, cascade_callbacks: true
```