# Carrierwave multi file (photo) upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, multifile-uploader

I have Ruby on Rails app and I use Carrierwave for uploading my images, but I need upload more than one image at a time. I find some jQuery plugins(uploadify, image-uplad) but I don't know how implement it to my app. I don't need a huge app/engine for it.

Answer (score 2):

Check it : http://lucapette.com/rails/multiple-files-upload-with-carrierwave-and-nested_form/

[Uploading multiple files at once to Rails app with Carrierwave (HTML5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447278/uploading-multiple-files-at-once-to-rails-app-with-carrierwave-html5)

Comment: Thank you, I found this [demo app](https://github.com/kdironside/carrierwave-multi-file-upload) . It's Rails 3.2.3 and It's look nice for me.

Comment: Link above needs credentials.